# Keyboard shortcut for 7z "Add to archive..."

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, 7-zip

I want to create a keyboard shortcut for the *Right click > Add to archive...* feature of 7z, in the Windows File Explorer.

This *nearly* works with AutoHotkey:

```
#z::
    SendInput {AppsKey}a{Enter}
    Return
```

Indeed <kbd>APPSKEY</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> is sometimes okay:

[image]

but sometimes not okay, for example, when the selected file is a Folder:

[image]

for which another menu item would be selected for the letter "A" (here, "Add to MPC-HC playlist").

Important notes:

- I could manually find in `regedit.exe` the various Context menu items for Files, for Folders, for every possible File extension (too many possible extensions!), but this would be too long... wouldn't it?  (*)
- I already tried with a *"Cascaded context menu"* for 7z (this is available in the *7z-File-manager  > Tools > Options... > 7-Zip* menu), but things are even worse. Depending on the context, the letter are not the same and then it's impossible to associate a consistent hotkey
- A solution would be that 7z would register `&Add to archive...` instead of just `Add to archive...` in the context menus. If I remember well `&` in the regedit context menu settings is what helps the context menu to use a letter shortcut. Is there an option for this? Sadly this doesn't seem available directly in 7-zip.

---

(*) Would it be still possible with few `regedit` editions? i.e. replace `Add to archive...` by `&Add to archive`? In how many keys/values should this be done? In:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\7-Zip
```

I see:

```
{23170F69-40C1-278A-1000-000100020000}
```

Can this be useful?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass    ; explorer

    #z::
        ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
        clipboard := ""                 ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
        Send, ^c                        ; copy selected item
        ClipWait, 1                     ; wait for the clipboard to contain data 
        if (!ErrorLevel)                ; If NOT ErrorLevel ClipWait found data on the clipboard
        {
            ; MsgBox, %clipboard%       ; display the path
            FileGetAttrib A, %clipboard%
            if InStr(A, "D")            ; is a folder
                SendInput {AppsKey}aa{Enter}
            else                        ; is a file
                SendInput {AppsKey}a{Enter}
        }
        else
            MsgBox, No file selected
        Sleep, 300 
        clipboard := ClipSaved         ; restore original clipboard
        VarSetCapacity(ClipSaved, 0)   ; free the memory
    return

#IfWinActive
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#ClipboardAll
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileGetAttrib.htm

**EDIT**

This should work if we select multiple files to ZIP:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass    ; explorer

    #z::
        folder := false
        file := false
        ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
        clipboard := ""                 ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
        Send, ^c                        ; copy selected item
        ClipWait, 1                     ; wait for the clipboard to contain data 
        if (!ErrorLevel)                ; If NOT ErrorLevel ClipWait found data on the clipboard
        {
            Loop, Parse, Clipboard, `n  ; split by linefeed
            {
                LoopField := trim(A_LoopField, "`r`n") ; trim CRs/LFs
                FileGetAttrib A, %LoopField%
                if InStr(A, "D")        ; is a folder
                    folder := true
                else                    ; is a file
                    file := true
            }
            if (folder) 
            {
                if (file)              ; folders and files
                    SendInput {AppsKey}a{Enter}
                else                   ; only folders
                    SendInput {AppsKey}aa{Enter}
            }
            else if (file)             ; only files     
                SendInput {AppsKey}a{Enter}
        }
        else
            MsgBox, No file selected
        Sleep, 300 
        clipboard := ClipSaved         ; restore original clipboard
        VarSetCapacity(ClipSaved, 0)   ; free the memory
    return
    
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think this would work if we select multiple files to ZIP (this is a common scenario) because of `FileGetAttrib A, %clipboard%`. Do you see a way that would allow multiple files?

Comment: See EDIT in this answer.